# How to fix EPDM to planters?

Tags: containers

I've seen that [EPDM rubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPDM_rubber) is a great material to cover the interior of composite planters but I have no idea about how to fix them to the planters. What's the right product and how to do it?

Their size is  about 6 meter x 0.50 cm x 0.60 cm

Answer (score 2):

I have used EPDM extensively for ponds and weed barriers.  It is very tough but the thickness means it is not flexible. By flexible I mean it does not drape like a fabric.  You do not give the dimensions of the planters your are using but EPDM will not work well in small ones.  You can fold it around corners.  Some tips:

- do your work with it when it has been in the sun a while.  Much easier to fold when it is warm
- you may find [expanding foam](https://www.google.ca/search?q=waterfall%20foam%20sealant) or [adhesives](https://www.google.ca/search?q=epdm%20bonding%20adhesives) but these products do not work well when the epdm can move due to water or seasonal changes.  They are for situations where the epdm is anchored and immobile on a flat surface
- for a large container you could try just letting the weight of the soil shape the epdm for you

Comment: Is this stuff 'pond liner' material?  Weed barrier?  Kevinsky?  Have no idea what EPDM is.after looking at some site.  If this is pond liner always use 2 layers.  A great product to use instead of pond liner to coat cinder block and make it water tight, still a bit flexible is Rhino Liner.  Amazing stuff.  But weed barriers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Given the shape of the planter I would need more than one piece to cover the sides,  that's why I was thinking to fix it

Comment: @Stormy  there is no need to use two layers, double the thickness and cost. For ponds a woven fabric between the liner and the ground is recommended.  For weed barriers it works great for weeds that spread underground.  There is always some left over after an install. A six or eight inch strip placed vertically in a slit trench works wonders

Comment: From experience not only of my own, using 2 layers is worth the extra money.  Have you ever had to redo an entire humongous water feature, a dog gone ostentatious water fall river thing?  Worth the extra protection.  For weeds?  Well, you know how I feel about plastic or barrier of any kind just to think one is defraying weeds?  Weeds are the lowest worry of any gardener, in any situation.   Just never ever have had a problem with weeds.   How does a left over eight inch wide strip help in a trench?  Landscape fabric was created to stop the loss of gravel into the soil.  Not as a weed stopper.

Comment: Do you know the evaporation formula?...holy moly...HUGE huge...eye opener and great to use to get clients understanding they do not need a 30' water fall for superior water sounds and  water ambiance triggers.  I saved my company from having to completely tear out and re construct a 30' humongous rock water fall, multi ponds, using jutting rockery so water flowing over it makes more sound...blah blah blah...bigger water features  never MAKE MONEY.  But I was able to show the exact amount of water they were using was lost to evaporation...not a leak.  big big whew!